# Show (.incl) tax and (.excl tax) after prices

Tags: magento2, tax, customer-group

I made two customer groups, one *with* Tax calculated in the product price and the other *without* the tax calculated in the product price. Now, whenever a customer group member is logged in with tax enabled, I want to show to product prices like so:

> $44,99 (incl. tax)

and when a customer group member is logged in from a group without tax, like so:

> $35,96 (excl. tax)

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've been looking in the core files for the file responsible for rendering the  `<span class="price">` but could not find it. Anyone who might know how to do this?